# Deleted $WORK Directory

Tags: command-line, environment-variables

So I made a mistake working on a school assignment and I'm curious what exactly it is that I did.

I used `ssh` to log in to a supercomputer provided for the class and used `scp` to copy a file to my `$HOME` directory.

I tried to copy the file from my `$HOME` directory to my `$WORK` directory using `cp file $WORK`. This resulted in a new file called `$WORK`.

I then tried to `rm $WORK`, froze, and logged back in to a banner informing me that:

```
The following filesystem(s) are currently unavailable:  /work
You will NOT be able to submit jobs while these are being worked on.
You will receive email when they/it are available again
```

The newly-created file `$WORK` is still present. So my guess is that `rm $WORK` attempted to/succeeded in removing whatever was referred to by the environmental variable `$WORK`? Or was that command evaluated to `rm -rf /*`, as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710545/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-environment-variables-in-rm-rf-statements) Stack Overflow post?

edit: I just realized that this isn't a Ubuntu-specific issue, as I believe the server is running RHEL. I assume whatever I did would be applicable to both distributions, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a tipical mistake using shell variables.

See explicit information about your mistake at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls

Additionally your should clear out what was the contents of your $WORK variable.

It seems that you copied the contents of the file "file" to a file named "$WORK" instead of copying to the file that is named in the $WORK variable. If you want to delete the new file please use quotes like:

```
rm  "$WORK"
```